# Autocomplete in text area in dojo 1.6

Tags: autocomplete, dojo

How can we do auto complete for simple text area in dojo 1.6?

I found some example in jQuery:

[jquery-textarea](https://github.com/mataki/jquery-textarea-imput-support)

This is an example of autocomplete text area in jQuery, I need the same in DOJO 1.6